# Oh MySQL, how doth thou join related records by date

Tags: mysql

I have what can only be described as a seemingly simple problem with most likely a simple solution; yet that simple solution escapes me. I've searched and trudged through the vast web of StackOverflow only to come up short finding only solutions that seem to be extremely complex. I've already *kind of* solved this problem, but, it's disgusting and I'm ashamed of it. Surely there is a better way, for there must be a Knight in shining MySQL armor wielding a query sword who can come up with a simple and elegant solution. Here goes:

For the sake of this question, we'll keep the two tables simple.

```
Table 1
users (user_id, active, name)
```

and

```
Table 2
user_projects (user_project_id, user_id, start_date, details)
```

In this case, records for users are added as needed. Related records are then added as projects are completed by users.

My question is: Using a query, how can I get 1 record containing all of the information in table 1 active users joined with the record from table 2 with **the most recent date** based on start_date?

In other words, if I have this:

```
| user_id | active | name  |
| 1       | 1      | brian |
```

and this:

```
| user_project_id | user_id | start_date | details |
| 1               | 1       | 2013-10-02 | proj 1  |
| 2               | 1       | 2013-11-26 | proj 2  |
| 3               | 1       | 2014-01-02 | proj 3  |
```

produce the query that gives me this:

```
| user_id | active | name  | user_project_id | user_id | start_date | details |
| 1       | 1      | brian | 3               | 1       | 2014-01-02 | proj 3  |
```

Oh please oh please let there be an answer for I will surely wither without one.

Comment: Just to be explicit: you want a row for each user and their most recent project? FYI, you're trying to find the 'groupwise maximum'. (Should help you google it in the future). It is possible to do it with one query (as demonstrated below), but it can be very inefficient - don't be afraid of doing some of the processing in code.

Comment: @aidan, Yes. Groupwise maximum; I had not heard that term before. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in MySQL there is not such things as `top` selectors, you can use triple `JOIN`, like:

```
SELECT
  user_projects.*,
  users.*
FROM
  (SELECT 
    MAX(start_date) AS max_date, 
    user_id
  FROM
    user_projects
  GROUP BY
    user_id) AS max_dates
  LEFT JOIN
    user_projects 
      ON max_dates.max_date=user_projects.start_date
      AND max_dates.user_id=user_projects.user_id
  LEFT JOIN
    users
      ON users_projects.user_id=users.user_id
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and less complex than what I've been seeing and far less complex than what I did. It's also the most accurate and versatile. Thank you very much.

Comment: The left join seems superfluous.

Comment: @Jack, this query definitely produced the desired output, but, I'd be interested to know if it could be improved further.

Comment: Note: if a user has two (or more) projects with the same `start_date`, you will see duplicated users in your result set.

Comment: Also, users with no projects will not appear in the result set

Comment: Yes, with duplicate maximum `start_date` for certain user it may be, but not across users (since first `JOIN` uses `user_id` in condition)

Comment: @eBrian I've added my own answer, so that basically tells you how I would have done it :)

Comment: @Jack it may be superfluous - if integrity is supported by DBMS (for example, FK) - however, I used common case (so where integrity isn't maintained, and, therefore, second table may contain unmatched records for first table)

Comment: Are you saying that there are people who don't use foreign keys? *gasp* :)

Comment: @Jack yes. I'm saying that (because OP didn't mentioned that, so I didn't assumed reference integrity)

Comment: I should have specified that. This *would* contain FKs.

Comment: Then you can easily replace `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` (btw, default `JOIN` is equal to `INNER JOIN` in MySQL, so you can use `JOIN` and save 5 symbols). It will be a little bit faster in common case

Answer (score 1):

First select the projects per user that are the most recent:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM user_projects a
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(start_date) AS max_start_date
  FROM user_projects
  GROUP BY user_id
) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.start_date = b.max_start_date
```

It creates a small helper table from `user_projects` comprising the user and for each row their most recent project date; to get all the corresponding table fields you must join that with `user_projects` again.

Then, you simply join `users` with the above outcome to get the final result:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN (
  SELECT a.*
  FROM user_projects a
  JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(start_date) AS max_start_date
    FROM user_projects
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.start_date = b.max_start_date
) c ON users.user_id = c.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u1.user_id, u1.name, u.strat_date, u.user_project_id, u.details
 from user_projects u
left outer join users u1 on u1.user_id=u.user_id
left outer join 
(select user_id, max(strat_date) as strat_date  user_projects group by user_id) as A
on A.user_id=u.user_id and A.strat_date=u.strat_date
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use top 1 and order by date

```
select top 1 a.user_id,a.name,b.user_project_id,b.user_id,b.start_date,b.details
from users a join users_project b on a.user_id = b.user_id
order by b.start_date desc
```

Sorry i didnt notice mysql tag in OP's question. You can use Limit keyword.

```
 select  a.user_id,a.name,b.user_project_id,b.user_id,b.start_date,b.details
from users a join users_project b on a.user_id = b.user_id
order by b.start_date desc Limit 1
```

Comment: There's no `top` selectors in MySQL